# Linux environment variable reset after restart

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

So I have this really nasty problem.

I once set up a tomcat Server on my raspberry pi. The version of it was 8.0.24. I've created a bash script which sets the variable $CATALINA_HOME=/home/pi/apache-tomcat-8.0.24 on each start.

Meanwhile the directory is /home/pi/tomcat - i removed the useless information.

I've changed the export in /etc/init.d/tomcat also, but it didnt help.
After every restart, CATALINA_HOME is set back to /home/pi/apache-tomcat-8.0.24 again.

Is there a way to see, which script sets the environmental variable?

Somewhere I told linux to change the path at startup to /home/pi/apache.. , but i cant find where.

Comment: You can try doing"grep -r CATALINA_HOME /etc" to find out where you are setting it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line in a few of the startup scripts to print the value of $CATALINA_HOME. Try adding:

```
echo "In $0, \$CATALINA_HOME is $CATALINA_HOME"
```

to your .bashrc before and after the call to /etc/bashrc
There's also a script called setenv.bash inside Tomcat that sets these types of variables. Take a look in there too.